# How to migrate an already set up one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ef-fluent-api

I have a `C#` `WPF` application using an `SQLite` database with `Entity Framework`. I have a `Contact` class which can have multiple messages, so there is a one-to-many relationship, set up the following way (simplified version):

```
public class Message {
    public int PK { get; set; }
    public int SenderKey { get; set; }
    public Contact Sender { get; set; }
}

public class Contact {
    public int PK { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Then I set the relationship using the Fluent API, the following way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.Sender)
                .WithMany(e => e.Messages)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.SenderKey);
}
```

I'm going to have lots of data (and also have lots of troubles with this circular dependency, especially on editing the objects in detached mode) so it's not a good idea to have that `Messages` collection in the memory for every contact. To avoid this, I'd like to get rid of that list, so it would be great to implement the 'Convention 1' from [the docs](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) (to just have the Contact object in the Message class and that's all).

The problem with this solution is that my app is already published, so I can't just simply change the structure, I need a migration. My question is that **how can I migrate this kind of relation set up by the Fluent API**?

I tried to remove the relationship from the `OnModelCreating`, but I got the following exception when I started the app:
`System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error no such column: Extent1.Sender_PK` (what is that Extent1 table?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I didn't have to implement a specific migration, just modify the following things:

1. Remove the relationship setup from the `OnModelCreating`
2. The previous step caused that "sql logic error" posted in the question. This was because the foreign key column name wasn't specified and the Entity Framework searched for a default column, which is in fact `Sender_PK`. So, in order to solve this, I added an annotation in the `Message` class, which tells the Entity Framework what is the foreign key column name for that `Contact` object:

```
public class Message {
    public int PK { get; set; }
    
    public int SenderKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SenderKey")]
    public Contact Sender { get; set; }
}
```

3. Remove the message list reference (`public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }`) from the `Contact` class.

So, after this three step modification I had the one-to-many relationship between the two tables and I could get rid of that list. Nothing else needed, it works perfectly with the old databases.